# How to make a single column abstract into two columns

Tags: apa-style, sharelatex, abstract, overleaf, apa6

I am using APA6 template provided by sharelatex. However, the template outputs a single column abstract in a two column document (as shown here: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/apa).

I want the abstract to be in the two columns as well. i.e. as shown in the image below. Is there a way to do it in latex?

[image]

Please let me know if any details are needed.

**EDIT**

The code looks as follows.

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}

\title{Example of an APA style for journal article}
\shorttitle{APA style}

\twoauthors{Author One}{Author Two}
\twoaffiliations{Institute of Psychology}{Freud's Institute}

\abstract{This is an example of a journal article using the \texttt{apa6.cls} document class to typeset manuscripts according to 6th edition of the Americal Psychological Association (APA) manual}

\rightheader{APA style}
\leftheader{Author One}

\begin{document}
\maketitle    

\section{Sample section}
Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. Sample text. 


\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Raaja Thanks a lot. What did you mean by MWE? :)

Comment: @Raaja Edited the question. thanks for helping me :)

Comment: If you don't want your document formatted in APA style, don't use an apa class. You are better of with `article`.

Comment: [off-topic] To me that would look very weird for many reasons, one of which is the redability.

Comment: To answer your question, yes, it can be done.  But I would strongly recommend you not do so.

Comment: @JohnKormylo If doing that is possible, can you please let me know how to do it. I still could not resolve my issue.

Comment: Try putting multicol inside a minipage.